# Reactive function not working in shiny ggplot. Plot is blank

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

Thank you in advance for the help. I am trying to reference a reactive dataframe in renderplot and then eventually I would also like to reference the same dataframe in a rendertable. the plot keeps showing up blank with no data. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? I am fairly new to shiny still, so sorry if its a beginner no brainer question.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Moving Average Backtest"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         dateRangeInput("DateRange","Select Dates"),
         numericInput("SDRoll","Select rolling Vol", value = 255)
      ),


  mainPanel(
     plotOutput("Chart"),
     tableOutput("Risk_Return")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {



 dateTriggerBegin<- reactive({input$DateRange[1]})
 dateTriggerEnd<- reactive({input$DateRange[2]})

 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(zoo)
 library(PerformanceAnalytics)
 library(quantmod)

 #setwd("P:/Anthony/R/Moving Average")
 Main_DF <- reactive({   

  Roll_Avg3 <- group_by(Roll_Avg2, Date)%>%
   summarize(Total_weighted_return = sum(TotalReturn)+1)%>% 
   filter(row_number() > 255)%>%
   filter(Date >= dateTriggerBegin() & Date <= dateTriggerEnd())%>%
   mutate(Total_Cum_Return = cumprod(Total_weighted_return))%>%
   mutate(Total_Cum_DollarRet = Total_Cum_Return*1000000)

  })     

output$Chart <- renderPlot({

  Roll_Avg4 <- Main_DF()$Roll_Avg3

  ggplot(Roll_Avg4, aes(x = Roll_Avg4$Date, y = Roll_Avg4$Total_Cum_DollarRet )+geom_line()

})
```

Comment: What happens when you remove `$Roll_avg3` from the render plot call?

Comment: If I remove RollAvg3 from my render plot call and then reference within ggplot like
ggplot(Roll_Avg3, aes(x = Roll_Avg3$Date, y = Roll_Avg3$Total_Cum_DollarRet))+geom_line()

then I get an error that says object: Roll_Avg3 not found

Comment: `Roll_Avg4 <- Main_DF()$Roll_Avg3` changes to `Roll_Avg4 <- Main_DF()` - leave your ggplot AS IS.

Comment: Boom! your the man! thank you. I knew it had to be something easy like that. much appreciated.

Comment: Aw. So If I were to add a another data frame below Roll_Avg3 the call in ggplot referencing Roll_Avg4 doesn't work. It appears that it only refers to the last line of code in Main_DF(). Is there any way to reference a specifc data frame within the reactive Main_DF?